# creating a file manager in python

Tags: python, pydev, glade

Good day to all. This is actually my first time ever posting a question so I'm gonna go straight to the point. Me and my team mates are actually working on an application using python as our programming language and we are stuck in finding ways on how to create a file manager using the said language.

We have been searching and scouring the web but we can't seem to find the appropriate answer for the questions.

We are trying to achieve something like this using `python` in either `eclipse` or using glade.

```
.-root
.  - dir_one
.    -file_one
.    -file_two
.    -file_three
.  -dir_two
.    -image_one
.    -image_two
```

Sorry, I can't seem to post images as of the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have problem with the GUI part, or finding the files and folders?

Comment: If you wanted to get straight to the point, you shouldn't have written all that stuff about getting straight to the point...

Comment: If the trouble is what to do you can goggle `xtree`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to print something like what you showed in your post, then what you are searching for is [os.walk.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

**[Here is a good example](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/03/python-oswalk-example/)** on how to use it.

And as Michael mentioned, the os module is probably filling most of your needs regarding file manager operations.

Comment: Thanks for the help! We will try to browse through the example and maybe find the solution for it..

Comment: Yep, i think you'll find the perfect start for your needs in this tuto :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you specify glade, I assume you're using GTK+.

As I see it, there are really two problems for you to solve:

- How to list/move/delete/copy files and directories. This problem is practically solved for you using python's `os` module ( http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html ), and GLib's GIO. (No docs AFAIK, I find it's quite trivial to work out what to do based on the C functions)
- How to make your interface. From the layout that you suggest, I think the Gtk.TreeView model/widget is what you're after: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html

Also, there's a relatively simple pre-made example here: http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/advancedwidgets/